# How to extract these 6 symbols (signatures) from paper (opencv)

Tags: opencv, contour, feature-extraction

I have an image:

[image: an image]

and I'm trying extract the signs one by one.
I tried `findContours()` but I got a lot of internal contours. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While finding contours always ensure that the regions of interest are in white. In this case, after converting the image to grayscale, apply an inverted binary threshold such that the signatures are in white. After doing so `findContours()` will easily find all the signatures.

**Code:**

The following implementation is in python:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\sign.jpg')

#--- Image was too big hence I resized it ---
image = cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)

#--- Converting image to grayscale ---
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#--- Performing inverted binary threshold ---
retval, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, type = cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imshow('sign_thresh_gray', thresh_gray)
```

[image]

```
#--- finding contours ---
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, \
                                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 100:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi = image[y  :y + h, x : x + w ]
        cv2.imshow('sign_{}.jpg'.format(i), roi)
        cv2.waitKey()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

Here I have some of the extracted signatures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: awesome!! Thanks